# Как переназначить главное меню НЕ используя админку в joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Есть ли возможность переназначать главное меню не заходя в админку. Мне нужно, что при проверки условия главным становилось конкретное меню.

```
if($a == $b){
  //главное меню menu1
}else if($a == $c){
   //главное меню menu2
}
..... т.д.
```

примерно так.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не понятен, но возможно это: 
http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: нет, совсем не то.